# Getting this error as No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel' in angular

Tags: angular

```
Already imported Formmodules in appmodule.ts but still getting this below error. Please help
```

**No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'.
123                         [ngModel]="sftpEffectiveStartDate" [max]="maxDate" [(ngModel)]="form1.sftpEffectiveStartDate" #sftpEffectiveStartDate="ngModel"**

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control" id="sftpEffectiveStartDate" name="sftpEffectiveStartDate" [ngModel]="sftpEffectiveStartDate" [max]="maxDate" [(ngModel)]="form1.sftpEffectiveStartDate" #sftpEffectiveStartDate="ngModel"                            aria-describedby="sftpEffectiveStartDate" formControlName="sftpEffectiveStartDate">

form1: any = {};
maxDate: Date = new Date();
ngOnInit() {
this.maxDate.setDate(new Date().getDate());
}
```

Comment: Can you add your AppModules.ts too?
It's https://angular.io/api/forms/FormsModule

Is the component also registered in the AppModule?

Comment: Please conform your component is register with appModule.ts or you need to import FormsModule in your registered module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `[ngModel]="sftpEffectiveStartDate"` from html and try